# Firestore security rules nested Collection Group query

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following rules:

```
 -> Requests
    -> documentID
        -> name: Andrey Solera
        -> email: someemail@example.com
        -> userID: 1234ID
        -> resolved: pending => (can also be accepted or rejected)
```

I want to be able to push a new document into the `Requests` node **if and only if** the `userID` of the person sending the request has **not** yet added a request.
I know that I can use the `userID` as the `documentID`, however, I want some kind of history of documents in case the user has made a request that has been rejected, and by using the `userID` as the `documentID` there's no possibility of having a history as far as I know.
Is it possible checking a nested object using Firestore security rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security rules can check whether a document exists at a specific path. They cannot query whether a document exists that matches other types of conditions however.

So if you have a document with the user's UID as its ID in a subcollection, you can check for that with an [`exists()` call](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents) in your rules.